UPDATE a column from table A if A.column values contain table B.column
I'm using Spark SQL. Table A contains two columns - CVEs, KEV. Table B contains column CVE. I would like to set A.KEV to 'True' if A.CVEs contains B.CVE (not equals). In SQL Server, this would be something like
UPDATE A
SET KEV = 'True'
FROM A
    JOIN B ON A.CVEs LIKE '%' + B.CVE + '%'

How can I convert this to Spark SQL, which throws an error for the above code, since the UPDATE...SET...FROM syntax is seemingly unsupported?

create a temporary table by inserting all your records with the updated values. After that Insert overwrite your target table with this temporary table union with the rest of the records for the target table that are not in temporary table so that it would have all records.
